# yum install updates up to a specific date

Tags: centos, yum

Is there a way to run `yum update`, but have it only install packages up to a certain date?

An update that took place overnight (as it does everynight), caused issues, and now after reloading CentOS, I want to install packages as if it was before yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the /etc/yum.conf options](http://linux.die.net/man/5/yum.conf) there appears to be an option `exclude` which will allow you to specify packages you wish to exclude from updates or installs. This could mean you could tell it not to update `packageName--packageVersion` if you know the packages that you do not wish to install.

Comment: @Jonathan. Does this not help in any shape or form?